# C++ english to morse code using two string arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, text

I am trying to get this to take in a string in english and then convert it into morse code, including spaces. thought this should work but when i enter a string to convert, there is no output, i hit enter and it stays on the enter a string screen, any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

```
int counter, option;
int length = 0;
//const int arraysize = 39;
string morse[39] = (".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....",
"..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", 
"...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", 
"...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", 
".-.-.-", "--..--", "..--..");

string alphabet[39] = ( "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
"K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", 
"Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "Stop", ",", "?");

int main()
{
    string english = "", coded, encoded, decoded;
    char letter, blank = " ";
    cout.precision(2);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);
    cout << "1 - Encode text to morse\n2 - Decode from morse to english\n3 - 
    Display Morse code\n4 - Quit\nSelect an option, 1 - 4: ";
    cin >> option;
    system("cls");

switch(option)
{
    case 1:
        morsedisplay();
        cout << "\nEnter the text that you want translated to Morse 
        Code: ";
        cin.ignore(100, 'n');
        getline(cin, english);
        length = english.length();
        for (int n = 0; n <= length - 1; n++)
        {
            letter = english.at(n);
            if (letter != ' ')
            {
                for(int counter = 0; counter < 39; counter++)
                {
                    string temporary;
                    temporary = toupper(letter);
                    if (temporary == alphabet[counter])
                    {
                        cout << morse[counter] << " ";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        break;
    case 2:
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Why the `cin.ignore`?

Comment: Hopefully this is only an exercise, as this program is horribly inefficient.  If the message is 1,000 characters, you may loop up to 38,000 times to complete the phrase.  A better implementation would be to use a lookup map.

Comment: where & what  is `morsedisplay();` post the full code !!

Comment: the morsedisplay() is just a function to display the english to morse code conversion chart

Comment: You have a concept problem here.  A *string* is usually more than one character.  A `char` type is a single letter or symbol.  Recommend you using an array of char for the alphabet.  This translates easier into the index for the Morse array.

Comment: BTW, for the index into the Morse array, you should subtract the value 'A' from the English letter.  This will adjust the index appropriate, since 'A' is the first letter in the array.

Comment: Your `cin.ignore` call should be `cin.ignore(100, '\n');` -- with backslash-n, for newline (left over after hitting enter during the option selection), not just the letter `'n'`.  Also, your array initializers shouldn't compile -- they have parentheses (`(...)`) when they need curlies (`{...}`).  Also, `blank = " ";` should probably be `blank = ' ';` because `blank` is a `char` value.